# EasyMock and parameterized tests (JUnit parameterized)

Tags: java, junit4, easymock, parameterized

I would like to use @Mock on a class inside parameterized test class. But for some reasons mockClassB is NULL. My code similar to

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ClassATest extends EasyMockSupport {

    private String uniqueIdentifier;
    private String value;

    @Mock
    private ClassB mockClassB;

    public ClassATest(String uniqueIdentified, String value) {
        this.uniqueIdentifier = uniqueIdentified;
        this.value = value;
    }

    ...

    @Parameterized.Parameters(name = "{index}: id = {0}; value = {1}")
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
                {"1", "val1"},
                {"2", "val2"}});
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        ...
        expect(mockClassB.someMethod(uniqueIdentifier)).andReturn(value);   // mockClassB is NULL
        replayAll();
        ....
    }
}
```

Is it possible to create a mocked object inside a parameterized class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EasyMock needs a rule or a runner to instantiate the annotated mocks. Since you are already using a runner, your only option is a rule. The following will work.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ClassATest extends EasyMockSupport {

    @Rule
    public EasyMockRule rule = new EasyMockRule(this);

    private String uniqueIdentifier;
    private String value;

    @Mock
    private ClassB mockClassB;

    public ClassATest(String uniqueIdentified, String value) {
        this.uniqueIdentifier = uniqueIdentified;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Parameterized.Parameters(name = "{index}: id = {0}; value = {1}")
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
                {"1", "val1"},
                {"2", "val2"}});
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        expect(mockClassB.someMethod(uniqueIdentifier)).andReturn(value);   // mockClassB is NULL
        replayAll();
    }
}
```

The alternative is to directly call `injectMocks` which is available on `EasyMockSupport`.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ClassATest extends EasyMockSupport {

    private String uniqueIdentifier;
    private String value;

    @Mock
    private ClassB mockClassB;

    public ClassATest(String uniqueIdentified, String value) {
        this.uniqueIdentifier = uniqueIdentified;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Before
    public void before() {
        injectMocks(this);
    }

    @Parameterized.Parameters(name = "{index}: id = {0}; value = {1}")
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
                {"1", "val1"},
                {"2", "val2"}});
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        expect(mockClassB.someMethod(uniqueIdentifier)).andReturn(value);   // mockClassB is NULL
        replayAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a setUp method :

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    initMocks(this);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, initMocks is not an EasyMock method

Comment: It is `injectMocks`

Answer (score 0):

Correct code will be looked following

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ClassATest extends EasyMockSupport {

    private String uniqueIdentifier;
    private String value;

    private ClassB mockClassB;

    public ClassATest(String uniqueIdentified, String value) {
        this.uniqueIdentifier = uniqueIdentified;
        this.value = value;
    }

    ...

    @Parameterized.Parameters(name = "{index}: id = {0}; value = {1}")
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
               {"1", "val1"},
               {"2", "val2"}});
    }

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        ...
        mockClassB = mock(ClassB.class);
        ...
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
       ...
       expect(mockClassB.someMethod(uniqueIdentifier)).andReturn(value);   // mockClassB will be mocked :)
       replayAll();
       ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. but then you are not using the annotation anymore. But of course, it works.